# Concurrent File upload to s3

Tags: file, file-upload, amazon-s3

I want to upload multiple files from HTML form to S3 using S3 POST. Currently for uploading a single file(2.5MB) S3 POST took 2 mins to upload. 
Is it possible to upload two files in parallel so that the total upload time to S3 is less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to do this. Basically, use an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) for each upload, so you can start them both in parallel.

Unfortunately, this will only work on browsers that let you access [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) inputs from JavaScript -- I don't think IE supports this.

A framework like jQuery or ExtJS may help you work around browser weirdness. ExtJS does file uploads by creating hidden iframes and submitting the form to load in the iframe. That way, you can create multiple hidden iframes and do multiple uploads at once.